# Example of increasing function such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there a strictly increasing continuous function $f:[0,m]\rightarrow [0,2000]$ such that $f(0)=0$, $f(m)=2000$ (where $m>2000$) and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$? If so, can someone give me an example?

What I'm trying to do is to apply a function to a bar chart that has values like 300, 40000, 10000, 30000, 12345 etc in order to 'normalize' the chart (make the chart look more friendly, without seeing a very big bar, then a tiny one). I applied the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{300/40000*x + 1}$, but the chart started to look weird because $f(40000)  \ne f(10000)+f(30000)$. This is why I'm searching for a function that satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Comment: like $f(x)=\frac12 x$?

Comment: That's all of them ($f(x)=ax$), yes?

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{2000}{m}x$ ?

Comment: Same thing, yes?

Comment: You don't mean $f(m)=2000 $ for all $m>2000$, do you?  That would not be strictly increasing.

Comment: the simplest would simply be $f: 0 \mapsto 0$ and $f: m\mapsto 2000$ and everything between maps proportionally.  It's straightforward to manipulate that to $f(x) = \frac {2000}m x$.  The issue is is that the *only* such function? What do you think?

Comment: @Mike said that there are no non-linear function that satisfy this condition? Can someone give me an explanation why?

Comment: @MTZ, assuming only $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$:  For any integer $k$, it should be clear that $f(kx) = kf(x)$.  We can show this, for example by induction.  Also, $f(x/2)+f(x/2) = f(x)$, so $f(x/2)=f(x)/2$.  Similarly $f(x/k)=f(x)/k$.  We can show the function is continous, and reason that $f(ax)=af(x).$ $\cdots$.

Comment: We also get from the above that  $f(x) = xf(1)$, so$ f(x) =x\cdot a$ for some $a$.

Comment: @mjw I meant how do we know that there are no other functions except the linear ones? How do I know that the linear functions are the only ones that satisfy my conditions?

Comment: That is what I was showing.  $f(ax)=af(x) \Rightarrow f(x)= f(1) x = \text{const.} \cdot x.$

Comment: @MTW what defines a linear function. How about this: Iff a function $f$ satisfying $f(0)=0$ is not linear then there are $a_x,a_y$; $a_x \not = a_y$, such that $f(x)=a_xx$ and $f(y)=a_yy$.

Comment: @mjw Got it! Thank you!

Comment: @Mike  Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \frac{2000x}{m}$ will do, as SenJen noted in the comments.

Comment: This is of the form $f(x) = ax$.  Here $a=2000/m$.

Comment: Thanks to @SenZen, who wrote this answer in a comment before Mike posted it as an answer.

Comment: @mjw  Mike and SenZen both wrote correct comments, one though, before the other.  Some of us give credit to commenters, who post before one posts one's answer.

Comment: Actually, they are the same exact example (Mike's and SZ's).  What's so great about this example.  J. W.'s answer is just as nice.  I actually like this answer!

Comment: I'm just not fond of users taking someone else's idea from a comment, and posting it as their own answer, without acknowledging the suggestion from the original user. Note, @mjw, you included this courtesy in your answer.  That's all I'm suggesting, and thanks for doing that.

Comment: Yes... I forgot to mention in the question that the plot of the graph must be a curve. However, I will accept the answer since it is bad. But I will really appreciate if you guys give me other examples, rather than $f(x)=ax$

Comment: I'm not a fan of answering questions in the comments nor am I a fan of downvoting answers to "easy" questions just because it may have been answered already in the comments. Answers to questions IMO should be posted as answers, and correct answers should not be downvoted. Many times when there is a question, multiple answers that really are just repeating the same line of reasoning, are posted, with no downvotes to the posters who were not first in posting their answer.

Comment: @MTZ if you want $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ to hold for all $x,y$ in the interval $[0,m]$ then the only functions that satisfy this are linear functions.

Comment: Keep in mind too @amWhy that people cross-post

Comment: @Mike with that in mind, I still do not understand why you did not acknowledge SenZen's comment.  Sounds like you're makiing an excuse.

Comment: @amWhy, okay, sorry for my question on your question.  Read it too quickly.  Now makes sense.

Comment: @Mike  is there a theorem that says so? (sorry for the dummy question)

Comment: @MTZ I don't know any theorem off the top of my head. The proof of this is somewhat involved. You would first show $f(0)$ must be $0$, and then show that there is an $a$ such that $f(x)=ax$ for all *rational* $x$. Then use continuity of $f$ to extend this to the irrationals.

Comment: I cross-posted...just saw that @mjw already said this!

Answer (score 2):

When @J.W.Tanner gave an example, he basically gave the prototype for all such functions.  $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$ is linear, and with your other conditions $$f(x)=ax, \quad \text{with }0<a<1.$$

**UPDATE**

Why is the function necessarily linear?  We reasoned in a comment above that $f(kx)=kf(x)$ and $f(x/k)=f(x)/k$ when $k$ is an integer.  Combining these, we have $f(px/q) = pf(x)/q,$ so it holds for rationals.  A continuity argument gives $f(a x)=af(x)$ for $a \in \text{Reals},$ which implies $f(x) = ax.$

Comment: Why "-1"?  Check again.

Comment: This answer is correct. I just upvoted

Comment: Okay, if you interpret the question to be for a specific $m$, then yes, $a=2000/m$.  I read it as "for some $m>2000$", so yes, that answer (originally given in the comment) would answer for a specific $m$.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong.  If we remove the condition that $f$ is increasing and allow $f$ to not be continuous it need not hold.  I think?  ..... Counter example is tedious and if $f(x) \ne f(1)x$, we would have to $f(x)=c$ and $f(qx) =qc$ for all rationals but this we have an irrational of the form $r + qx$ for some rational $r$ we must have $f(r+qx) = ar +qc$ and... well, it gets tedious to show we can partion the reals... I think.  I'm too lazy and tired....

Comment: $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ is a very strong condition.  I think it implies continuity.

Comment: @Mike, thank you!  Appreciate your vote.

Comment: @mjw of course, your answer was correct, it deserved the upvote. Now you do need to explicitly state continuity or strictly increasing a priori, otherwise why wouldn't $f(x) = ax$ for the rationals and $f(x)=bx$ for the irrationals work. The strictly increasing or even nondecreasing would force the continuity condition however.

Comment: $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.  What if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What about $x=5-\sqrt{2}$ and $y=5+\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: You are right, there are exceptional cases where continuity is not guaranteed.  Looks like it is known that additive functions are linear for rationals, but by not assuming the axiom of choice, other constructions are possible for the irrationals:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968648/does-all-additive-functions-are-linear-imply-every-set-of-reals-is-measurable

Comment: @mjw good point. Constructing a counterexample does seem to be rather deep and the example I gave would not suffice. I will look over that link

Answer (score -2):

First of all note that any function with given condition must be $f(x)=ax$, $a\in\mathbb R$ (real numbers).
In our case $a=2000/m$.
So required function is $f(x)=2000x/m$.
Please verify this function follow all your given conditions.

Comment: This question has already been asnwered (in comments, in answers, and one answer was even accepted).  Why post a repeat answer?